# SQL PHP Select columns with several conditions in same query

Tags: php, mysql, select

I can't figure out how to make a selection of the matches between 2 teams even if is at home or away.

Example:

I have this table:

```
MatchID  |  status |  date   |   short (home) |  opponent (Away)
1           ENDED      XXX       TEAM A          TEAM B
2           ENDED      XXX       TEAM B          TEAM A
3           ENDED      XXX       TEAM C          TEAM B
4           ENDED      XXX       TEAM D          TEAM A
```

I have a lot of matches and I want to make a module where I can show all previous matches between team A and team B. (even if is at home or away).

Right now this is my code, but is only showing 1 match of 2 possible matches.

```
$ergebnis = safe_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE status='ENDED' AND ((opponent = '".$opp_match."' AND short = '".$short_match."') OR (opponent = '".$short_match."' AND short = '".$opp_match."')) ORDER BY date LIMIT 0,5");
```

And I want to limit 0,5. Just want the last 5 matches between the 2 teams.

"opp_match" and "short_match" are connections to the other module. When I'm check the match I can check home team and away team with those.

With or without the limits I can't show more than one result.

I just want to show matchID 1 and 2. But right now I'm just getting matchID 1.

EDIT: I tried another way but I'm loading all ended matches.

```
   $ergebnis = safe_query("SELECT * FROM ".PREFIX."upcoming WHERE status='ENDED'"); 
   $i=1;
   while($ds=mysql_fetch_array($ergebnis)) {

   if($ds['short']==$short_match AND $ds['opponent']==$opp_match) {
            eval ("\$matches = \"".gettemplate("matches")."\";");
            echo $matches;
    }
    elseif($ds['opponent']==$short_match AND $ds['short']==$opp_match) {
        eval ("\$matches = \"".gettemplate("matches")."\";");
        echo $matches;
    }
    else echo '';
```

$i++;
}

Comment: You mention things like opponent and short in your query but that doesn't seem to make any sense in your table. Also to get the last 5 matches you'd need to either (a) have a date associated with a match or (b) let us know if bigger `matchId` means later date

Comment: you are right. I missed some points there. I already change some info, could you give me an hint now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will this work?

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE status = "ENDED"
AND 
(
    (opponent = "team1" AND short = "team2")
    OR
    (opponent = "team2" AND short = "team1")
)
ORDER BY MatchID DESC
LIMIT 5;
```

This assumes that if one match has a smaller ID than another, it has been played before the other.

Comment: Worked xD. I tried another way but I'm loading all ended matches. see above pls.